# JPA Cannot update or delete parent entity

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to save directed graphs into a database using JPA and I can create the entities the first time around and even make associations between them, but as soon as I try to delete one of them, it fails.

The classes are defined like this:

```
public class Node {
    @Id
    Long id;

    String name;

    Double weight;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    Node nextNode;

}
```

I don't need/ this to be a bidirectional relationship. I've also tried setting the nextNode attribute to null, then merging, then deleting but it doesn't seem to work and always gives the same error: cannot update or delete parent

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure, that Node you are deleting is not referenced from other Node-s. I.e. set nextNode to null not in node which is being deleted, but in node referencing it.

Possible solution using hibernate anotation:

```
@OnDelete(action=OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
```

generates the foreign key as : "ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;"